Python (unit test) and Pytest both are recognized by Test Explorer (Python Test for VS code) in VS code Playwright
I am setting up Playwright Python project for automation testing in VS code. I installed plug-in Python Test for VS code.
My Test file name is test_example.py
I have selected pytest while configuring Test explorer. Also, I have set pytest enabled and unit test disabled in setting.json file for vs.
But, my test explorer shows 2 test folders, looks like 1 folder identified as pytest e.g.<project name> - pytests and other is like Python Tests.
I tried all solution available on Google, chatgpt and copiolet but no success
I want to see only 1 test folder that is for pytest.
Has anyone faced it and have any solution
I set correct setting.json file and selected only pytest while Test explorer configuration
PLEASE REFER BELOW IMAGE:


It has been resolved when I used "Pytest Runner for Visual Studio Code" test explorer instead of "Python Test for VS code" test explorer
